# Tab control to handle child windows in an MDI form (VB.NET)

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, controls

My application uses an MDI form, and there are instances where the end user will need multiple child windows open at a time.  I need an easy way for the user to switch between windows, which made me think of using tabs kinda like Firefox, or like the tabs in the Visual Studio IDE up at the top where you can switch between open forms and code files.

I'm curious if there is a control in .NET that will already do this?  I would rather not re-invent the wheel if I can help it.  Google has failed me thus far.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a very handy MDI Window Manager control:

http://www.codeplex.com/mdiwinman

Answer (score 1):

I know this sounds obvious but have you looked into the tab control.  You can configure it so the tabs are at the top.

Comment: I could make the standard tab control work, I was just curious if there was a control in existence already that knew to look for child windows.

Answer (score 0):

Standard shortcut for this in Windows is `Ctrl+Tab`.

Edit:
Have you looked at this [article](http://www.vbaccelerator.com/home/VB/Code/Controls/Tab_Controls/MDI_Tabs/article.asp)?

Comment: I know, but most of my users are not that savvy.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tab control. For each open document, you can associate an instance of a class or user control (to handle the document) with a tab page. Sometimes it is useful to put a frame on the tab page and treat it like you would a form in a single document application.

An alternative to tabs is the "traditional" MDI application. While this isn't considered socially acceptable any more, at least by many people, it's still supported in VB.net. To make an MDI app, create a parent MDI form. This is a normal form with the IsMdiContainer property set to true. A child form is a normal form with the MdiParent property set to the parent MDI form at runtime.